# How do I make my C# PictureBox propagate mouse events? (screenshot provided)

Tags: c#, forms, events, picturebox

I am creating a program using C# forms which acts as an overlay on top of another application's window. The whole form is pretty much a transparent PictureBox which spans across the entire area and draws shapes here and there.

Right now, I can only interact with the underlying window where the overlay is fully transparent, how do I make the non-transparent areas not intercept mouse events?

For clarity, here's a screenshot:
[image]

Skype is the underlying application. My overlay draws the blue (and gray) boxes. I need to be able to click the links beneath the boxes.

Unfortunately, I have no code to show, since I'm not sure which part of the program actually handles things like this.

Thanks.

Comment: ` I can only interact with the underlying window where the overlay is fully transparent` so you can click `_ibrahimovic_amazing_bicycle/`. And you need the link below `never heard` should not be clickable. Right?

Comment: Thats how it works at the moment. I want both areas to be clickable.

Answer (score -1):

You could try subscribing to the shapes click event and then forwarding the event onto the "overlayed" window via some Windows APIs. If you have a pointer to the main window of the application (either you started it yourself via a Process object or you get it some other way) you can simply send mouse events to that window.

Here is an example that takes the current point of the screen and sends it to the first instance of Skype.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct LParamLocation
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int Number;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short X;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public short Y;

    public static implicit operator int(LParamLocation p)
    {
        return p.Number;
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
    LParamLocation points = new LParamLocation();
    points.X = (short)PointToScreen(e.Location).X;
    points.Y = (short)PointToScreen(e.Location).Y;

    SendMessage(process[0].MainWindowHandle, 0x201, 0, points); //MouseLeft down message
    SendMessage(process[0].MainWindowHandle, 0x202, 0, points); //MouseLeft up message
}
```

Alternativly you could try adding a window style to tell it to pass through all mouse events.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    int style = GetWindowLong(Handle, -20);
    style |= 0x00000020; // Enables Pass-Through of events
    style |= 0x00080000; // Enables Pass-Through to layered windows
    SetWindowLong(Handle, -20, style);
}
```

Comment: These mouse messages are posted, not sent.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  That it works for you is no guarantee that it works everywhere.  There no point in not doing it correctly.  Including declaring it properly (wp and lp are IntPtr) and using correct coordinates.

Comment: @HansPassant So how would you suggest doing it? Instead of down voting, why not post an answer? The fact that PostMessage does not work on anything I tried, as well as seeing this being documented all over StackOverflow and other places suggests this is the way to go.